# Using Django in a multithreading code

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am running a python script using django ORM to handle calls to the database.

I have the following code:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.submit(process, 2)
    executor.submit(process, 1)

@transaction.atomic
def process(counter)
    MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=counter).delete()
    users = <create User object)
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(users)
```

I am using django default behavior which sets the auto-commit to True.

When I debug the code, it looks that django uses the same connection among the application, and therefore, the last process that will exit process method, will commit all the transactions that are using the connection.

How can I prevent it to happen? 
I would like django to close (and commit) the connection at the end of each method so each thread could be handled separately.

Comment: Do you need these users in the code after? Or could you use celery?

Comment: I don't need the objects in the code afterwards

Comment: As a rule of thumb, whenever you want to do something concurrently inside Django, you should use celery project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). You will need [Redis](https://redis.io/) or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), to send messages between Django and Celery.

```
@app.task
def process(counter):
    MyModel.objects.filter(user_id=counter).delete()
    users = <create User object)
    MyModel.objects.bulk_create(users)
```

After that, use `apply_async`

```
process.apply_async((2,))
process.apply_async((1,))
```

Setting this up is a bit more complicated, but works well.